# Joomla Search Bar not loading userstate

Tags: php, joomla

I am implementing Joomla searchbar in a component. But for some reasons it is not loading the userState so the dropdowns are not working. The filters are working properly.

**XML Form:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fields name="filter">

        <field
                name="filter_search"
                type="text"
                label="COM_BANNERS_SEARCH_IN_TITLE"
                hint="JSEARCH_FILTER"
                class="js-stools-search-string"
        />

    </fields>

    <fields name="list">

        <field name="type" default="0" type="list" onchange="this.form.submit();" label="COM_RDAUTOS_CATEGORY_TYPE">
            <option value="0">COM_RAUTOS_PLS_SELECT</option>
            <option value="1">COM_RDAUTOS_VEHICLES</option>
            <option value="2">COM_RDAUTOS_PARTS</option>
        </field>

        <field name="state" default="0" type="list" onchange="this.form.submit();" label="COM_RAUTOS_PLS_SELECT">
            <option value="0">COM_RAUTOS_PLS_SELECT</option>
            <option value="1">COM_RAUTOS_UNPUBLISHED</option>
            <option value="2">COM_RAUTOS_PUBLISHED</option>
        </field>

    </fields>
</form>
```

**I have added this to my view.html.php file:**

```
// Joomla Core functionality for filtering
$this->state               = $this->get('State');
$this->filterForm          = $this->get('FilterForm');
$this->activeFilters       = $this->get('ActiveFilters');
```

**I have added this to the model:**

```
function __construct($config = [])
{
    if (empty($config['filter_fields']))
    {
        $config['filter_fields'] = [
            'state',
            'type',
        ];
    }

    parent::__construct($config);
```

}

And this for requesting the variables:

```
$state  = $this->getState('list.state');
$type   = $this->getState('list.type');
$search = $this->getState('filter.filter_search');
```

**default.php**

```
echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.searchtools.default', ['view' => $this]);
```

After I have selected a value in the searchtool bar it does filtering and everything works, but the selected value is not being selected in the select boxes. So we don't know what has been filtered.

Anyone that might know a solution?

Comment: You might like to post your question on the Joomla Stack Exchange site to gain the attention of a more dedicated audience. Note, in your **Administrator** -> **Help** tab, the 2nd last item says **Stack Exchange** <-- this is where the Joomla team encourages you to post your Joomla-specific questions and issues when you need support.

Comment: If you would like to migrate this page to [joomla.se] Stack Exchange,  you may flag your own question and requestion migration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `state` name of your filter field. The model already has a variable called `state`. I guess if you change the name state to something else like `status` things should work as expected.

Comment: I am getting clueless... This is not working either, something strange is happening.